# Mac SSD not showing in disk utility

Tags: disk-utility

I have a Macbook Air that will not boot.
When starting into network recovery mode, I go into disk utility and all that shows up is a 1.2 GB Mac OS X base system virtual disk, and not my SSD.

If I open Terminal in recovery mode and type diskutil list, I get a list including that Mac OS X Base System disk, as well as 10 disks listed, each about 500kb in size.

I have tried running fsck, however it just verifies that the base system disk is OK, but does not check the actual SSD.

Is this confirmation that the SSD drive needs replacement, or are there any further steps I can take to attempt to repair the disk?